# error when the client wants to connect to the server

Tags: java, connection, client, client-server

suppose we use the following classes to illustrate a client and a server :

## Client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private PrintWriter toServer;
    private BufferedReader fromServer;
    private Socket socket;

    public Client() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
    }

    public void openStreams() throws IOException {
        toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void closeStreams() throws IOException {
        fromServer.close();
        toServer.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public void run() throws IOException {
        openStreams();
        String msg = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        toServer.println("Hello from Client.");
        while (!"exit".equals(msg)) {
            System.out.println(">");

            toServer.println("msg");
            String tmp = fromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server said: " + tmp);
        }

        closeStreams();
    }
}
```

## Server

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class myServer {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static PrintWriter toClient;
    private static BufferedReader fromClient;

    public static void run() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Server is waiting for connections...");

        while (true) {
            openStreams();
            processClient();
            closeStreams();
        }
    }

    public static void openStreams() throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        toClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public static void closeStreams() throws IOException {
        fromClient.close();
        toClient.close();
        socket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public static void processClient() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
        String msg = fromClient.readLine();
        toClient.println("Client said " + msg);
    }
}
```

if , we run the server first and then after server is ready, we run the client, we would get the following error:

```
Error in Client Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

what is the problem?

Comment: You need to show the stack trace and identify the source line that throws the exception.

Comment: @JimGarrison it doesnt show any line as the point of the error and that line is the only line of the trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to use older version of java, similar thing happened to me and when i used sdk 1.6 instead of 1.7 everything fixed

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about your code

```
while (true){
    openStreams(); 
    processClient();  
    closeStreams();
}
```

In this case, the socket connection has always been reset. As a result, the Client cannot create the socket connection successfully.
You should let you code be like:

```
openStreams();
while(someCondition){
    processClient();
}
closeStream();
```